# MySQL Join Condition with Subtraction

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am joining two tables on a TINYINT column, which works perfect, like:

```
table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.col = table2.col
```

Now I would like to join records, where value of table1.col is greater by one than table2.col:

```
table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.col = (table2.col - 1)
```

Unexpectedly that returns an empty result.

Why? Can someone clarify that and help me?

Thanks in advance,
Sascha.

Comment: Presumably because there are no rows that match the condition.  Can you provide sample data?  Or better yet, an example on SQL Fiddle?

Comment: @michel-sim . . . I believe your answer is correct.  If table1.col is 10, then table2.col would be 9 -- the condition in the question is backwards.

Comment: Correct! I seem to be a victim of my own lack of sleep.
It has to be: table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON (table1.col - 1) = table2.col.
Its just simple math...

Comment: I've undeleted and clarified my answer, please vote for it then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your join condition is subtracting the wrong column - since `table1.col` is greater by one, to equalize the values you need to subtract 1 from it, or add one to `table2.col`, for example:

```
table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON (table1.col - 1) = table2.col
```

For a concrete example, suppose a row in `table 1` where `table1.col=8` needs to be matched with a row in `table2` where `table2.col=7` - you need to subtract 1 from 8 or add 1 to 7.

Comment: that would mean t1.col is 1 less than t2.col

Comment: I would write this as `table1.col = table2.col + 1` . . . but there is no difference.

Comment: @PhilCross No, think of it this way: Table1.com = 11. Table2.col = 1. Table1.col - 1 (11-1) = Table2.col (10).

Comment: @PhilCross - I'd appreciate it if you ask for clarification instead of instantly downvoting people, especially when your math turns out to be incorrect

Comment: @michel-slm I'd appreciate it if you got your facts right before incorrectly stating that I down voted you. I didn't.

Comment: @PhilCross my bad, someone did and coupled with your comment I assumed it was you